# Pop-up menu is not fully visible in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I am just evaluating IntelliJ IDEA. Installed it with default procedures.

I created a simple Spring project and when I right click on the project, not able to see the the bottom part of the pop up menu. The issue is because of my laptop screen's height is less and could not fit the entire set of pop-up menu items.

In eclipse there is a drop down arrow, so that I can scroll to the menu items, which do not fit in the screen.  How can I get the similar eclipse functionality in IntelliJ?

[image]

Comment: I suggest asking this in the JetBrains forums, rather than here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are only missing one useful feature (Genereate Java code from wsdl). I would ignore it unless you need to generate such code.

If you want to run this generation you can do this with `Ctrl + Shift + A` (and start typing feature name)

//btw, it is better to make code generation in maven anyway

Comment: Thanks for the information. Somehow you were able to figure out that the missing menu item.  But I feel this is an issue.